# Scala private apply method?

Tags: scala, methods, apply, private

I'm currently making a class that can store English words. I want to make it as safe as possible(if an input is invalid - return error message) and here is where I'm lost. I have this code that stores an English word:

```
  case class English_LT_Word private (word: String)
  object English_LT_Word {
    def apply(word: String) = new English_LT_Word(word)
    def createNewWord(word: String): Either[String, English_LT_Word] = {
      if (word.length > 0 && word.forall(x=>consonants.contains(x) || vowels.contains(x))) Right(apply(word))
      else Left("'" + word + "'" + " is an invalid word")
    }
  }
```

In this example i can create any English word like this:

```
val english = English_LT_Word.apply("Awesome")
val english = English_LT_Word.createNewWord("Awesome")
```

And here i have a dillema on what to use and it's not pretty. How do I do this correctly? Making .apply() method private is impossible because (long story short) compilers will be out of sync. I want to only be able to create my word by using .createNewWord() method. Any ideas?

Thank you!! ^^

Answer (score 3):

You can define your custom case companion apply under 2.12 or under 2.11 with `-Xsource:2.12`.

```
$ ~/scala-2.11.12/bin/scala -Xsource:2.12 
cat: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/release: No such file or directory
Welcome to Scala 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.util._

case class Word private (text: String)
object Word {
  def apply(s: String): Either[String, Word] =
    if (s.nonEmpty) Right(new Word(s)) else Left("Empty word!")
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.util._
defined class Word
defined object Word

scala> Word("")
res0: scala.util.Either[String,Word] = Left(Empty word!)

scala> Word("ok")
res1: scala.util.Either[String,Word] = Right(Word(ok))
```

Comment: do you need `new` in your apply for a case class?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley I was just showing that they made it possible to write your own apply, replacing the synthetic one. So it is necessary to use the constructor here. `C(x)` is rewritten to `new C(x)` after type checking.

Answer (score 2):

Create a simple class with companion object which can create a correct instance of `EnglishWord`

The instance has to be created using via companion object. Compiler does not allow if you directly create the instance using `new` keyword

```
class EnglishWord private (word: String)

object EnglishWord {

 def createEnglishWord(word: String): Either[String, EnglishWord] = {

  if (word.length > 0 &&
    word.forall(x => consonants.contains(x) || vowels.contains(x)))
    Right(new EnglishWord(word))
  else Left("'" + word + "'" + " is an invalid word")

 }

}
```

Comment: I've never understood this. If you do `val w = EnglishWord(...)`, w is an Either not an EnglishWord. I don't have any other suggestions, but this strikes me as a confusing API. I think if we're not going return an instance of the corresponding class, we shouldn't use apply

Comment: Working with "algebraic types" like Either and Option is very standard practice in Scala. It's good to become familiar with them; they're super useful and once you get your head around them I find them to be one of the best features of the language. Think of using Either here instead of using a try/catch in Java.

Comment: @Metropolis I agree re Option and Either. What I don't get is saying `= A()` and getting `Either[_, A]`. It's an API quibble rather than a Either & Option quibble

Answer (score 2):

I'd do almost what you're already doing, but without apply ...

```
class English_LT_Word private (word: String)

object English_LT_Word {
  def create(word: String): Either[String, English_LT_Word] = {
    if (word.length > 0 && word.forall(x=>consonants.contains(x) || vowels.contains(x)))
      Right(new English_LT_Word(word))
    else
      Left("'" + word + "'" + " is an invalid word")
  }
}
```

or you could imitate some of the collections API e.g. headOption

```
object English_LT_Word {
  private def isValidWord(s: String) = !s.isEmpty && s.toLowerCase.forall(('a' to 'z').contains)

  def createOption(word: String): Option[English_LT_Word] = {
    if isValidWord(word) Some(new English_LT_Word(word)) else None
  }
}
```

then the behaviour's clear (I took the liberty of adapting the validation, ignore if you like)